# How to check the time range if already in use in MSSQL using VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have two fields start time and end time, how can i check if the time is already in use. how to select query in MSSQL?

example:

```
room   starttime  endtime
 1     1:00        2:00
```

If i try to insert between those time i cannot save.

thanks in advance

```
   cn.Close()
        cn.Open()
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * from Settings_Curriculum_Subject_Selected where start_time >= '" & cbStartTime.Text & "'AND end_time <= '" & cbEndTime.Text & "'"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, cn)
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim roomx As Boolean
        roomx = False
        While rdr.Read()
            roomx = True
        End While
        rdr.Close()
```

Comment: And I don't see where you're inserting - you're just selecting.

Comment: how to use BETWEEN with two fields?

Comment: What `cbStartTime.Text` equals to before executing?

Answer (score 0):

Say, I have the following table:

```
create table dbo.TimeTable
(
    room int null,
    starttime time null,
    endtime time null
);

insert into dbo.TimeTable values
(1, '1:00', '2:00'),
(2, '3:00', '5:00');
```

This code selects `room`s where time is `1:30`:

```
Sub TestDatabase()
    Dim connStr = "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;" +
                "Database=StackOverflow;" +
                "Trusted_Connection=Yes"
    Using conn = New SqlConnection(connStr)
        conn.Open()
        Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TimeTable WHERE @ATime BETWEEN starttime AND endtime;"
        Using comm = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
            Dim t = TimeSpan.Parse("1:30")
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ATime", t)
            Using reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    Console.WriteLine(reader("room"))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

As you can see, you can use [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan) to obtain time.

Comment: i have two field.

Comment: Can you use two time fied?

Comment: @JomarkDelRosario In answer you can see a sample table I was testing the code on. As you can see, there are three fields: 1) room 2) starttime and 3) endtime. Also I inserted two rows with data. One of them has starttime 1:00 and endtime 2:00. The source time is 1:30 which falls into this region. So, the output is `1` (`room`). Using [BETWEEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql), I select a room.

Comment: @JomarkDelRosario It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. When you fetch some records, you just assign `True` in each iteration.

Comment: There is a problem with this, in that as it stands it will still allow double-booking where the start time is earlier than the previously booked start time, but the end time is within (or later than) the previously booked end time.

Comment: @peterG I just made fetching records who fall into time range. I don't know what business logic is there - I just answered a question.

Comment: @JohnyL Well, the OP's question refers to the time being 'in use' and the fields are room number, starttime and endtime, so I think the reasonable inference is that this is for some sort of room reservation system.